# Execute equation from the elements of a list and multiindex dataframes in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following list and dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("A1", "A"), 
                                  ("B1", "B"), 
                                  ("C1", "C")])
data = [[5, 10, 40], [2, 15, 70], [6, 14, 60]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
lst = [5, '*', 'A1.A', '+', 'C1.C']
```

The way the column multiinxed names are listed in the list can change if it can help.

I would like to create a code to execute the equation in the lst like `5 x df['A1','A'] + df['C1','C']` returning the following result:

```
data = [[65], [80], [90]]
dresult = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['M'])
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to rework your strings to `` `A1.A` `` (with backticks) and flatten the index to pass to [`DataFrame.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
query = ''.join([f'`{x}`' if (isinstance(x, str) and '.' in x) else str(x)
                 for x in lst])
# '5*`A1.A`+`C1.C`'

out = df.set_axis(df.columns.map('.'.join), axis=1).eval(query).to_frame('M')
```

Or using [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) and the DataFrame variable name:

```
query = ''.join([f'df.{x}' if (isinstance(x, str) and '.' in x) else str(x)
                 for x in lst])
# '5*df.A1.A+df.C1.C'

out = pd.eval(query).to_frame('M')
```

Output:

```
    M
0  65
1  80
2  90
```

##### reproducible code

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

print(sys.version)
print(pd.__version__)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("A1", "A"), 
                                  ("B1", "B"), 
                                  ("C1", "C")])
data = [[5, 10, 40], [2, 15, 70], [6, 14, 60]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
lst = [5, '*', 'A1.A', '+', 'C1.C']

query = ''.join([f'df.{x}' if (isinstance(x, str) and '.' in x) else str(x)
                 for x in lst])
out = pd.eval(query).to_frame('M')
print(out)
```

Comment: the query string is the following and it doesn't work: 5 *`A1 .A `+`C1 .C `

Comment: @Thanasis can you provide a reproducible example? I tested your current inputs and this works

Comment: I get the following error:
```5 *`A1 .A `+`C1 .C ` ```
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add the self-contained code that you used which reproduces this issue?

Comment: I added my fully reproducible code (which works for me), please run it in a clean python shell and provide the output. I'm using python 3.11.1 and pandas 1.5.3

Comment: It works now. I think I was using the first query construction on your suggestion

Comment: Indeed, the two queries are not compatible ;)